# Loopback project broken after upgrade

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

After creating a model with the command "lb4 model", it asked me to update the dependencies, after installing when compiling it throws this error, how can I fix it?

```sh
> adselfservice@1.0.0 build C:\Users\PC\WebstormProjects\adselfservice-node-backend
> lb-tsc

src/__tests__/acceptance/test-helper.ts:57:38 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'AdSelfServiceApplication' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RestApplicationLike'.
  Property 'restServer' is missing in type 'AdSelfServiceApplication' but required in type 'RestApplicationLike'.

57   const client = createRestAppClient(app);
                                        ~~~

  node_modules/@loopback/testlab/dist/client.d.ts:20:5
    20     restServer: RestServerLike;
           ~~~~~~~~~~
    'restServer' is declared here.

src/application.ts:20:32 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof RestApplication' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<{ readonly options: ApplicationConfig; re
adonly state: string; controller: <T>(controllerCtor: Constructor<T>, nameOrOptions?: string | BindingFromClassOptions | undefined) => Binding<...>; ... 53 more ...; listenerCo
unt: (type: string | symbol) => number; }>'.
  Construct signature return types 'RestApplication' and '{ readonly options: ApplicationConfig; readonly state: string; controller: <T>(controllerCtor: Constructor<T>, nameOrO
ptions?: string | BindingFromClassOptions | undefined) => Binding<...>; ... 53 more ...; listenerCount: (type: string | symbol) => number; }' are incompatible.
    The types returned by 'controller(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("C:/Users/PC/WebstormProjects/adselfservice-node-backend/node_modules/@loopback/rest-explorer/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/binding").Binding<T>' is no
t assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/PC/WebstormProjects/adselfservice-node-backend/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/binding").Binding<T>'.
        Types have separate declarations of a private property '_scope'.

20   ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[image: LogImage]
[image: IDEImage]

Comment: For future reference, this qn has also been posted in the community Slack: https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1599015999262500

Comment: I am not sure this is related to the update you made. It may be a simple coincidence, as you restarted your api server after the dependencies update. If you look in `application.ts`, don't you have some errors when you extend the ServiceMixin? I had the same error and it was because I had not services to declare in my `Application` class (I copied the code from the shopping example on GitHub).